# imagemagick using contiguous data to "white out" overlapping objects in object bounding boxes

Tags: imagemagick

Trying to use imagemagick to segment objects cleanly into their own bounding boxes from a series like this image where parts of another object should be "whited out", in another object's bounding box.

[image]

For example, results like (instead of containing either part of the hand or the suitcase):

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459722/imagemagick-return-the-bounding-box-of-each-contiguous-object/77461776#77461776

Comment: this case the bounding boxes overlap...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Imagemagick with [connected components processing](https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php) to create an image whose gray levels are the ids of the individual components. Then convert each gray level one at a time to a binary image for that region. Then use that to mask out the regions one at a time.

First threshold the image allowing some tolerance for the JPG compression.  Then clean that image up with some morphology open and close.  Then use connected components processing to both create an image coded with the ids for each region and also get the ids for each white region and store those ids in an array.

Next loop over each id in the array and get the id and convert that to a value representing percent of gray level relative to the quantum range, (nominally 65535 for 16-bits). Then use that value to convert the gray level in the id image to binary showing only the region for that id. Then use that as a mask to extract only that region in a white background and save the result.

Input:

[image]

Imagemagick 6 Unix Syntax:

```
idArr=(`convert image.jpg -negate -threshold 2% -bordercolor black -border 5 \
-morphology open diamond:1 -morphology close diamond:4 -shave 5 -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:exclude-header=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 id_image.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://g'`)
echo ${idArr[*]}
num=${#idArr[*]}

fuzz=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:0.5*100*/quantumrange]" info:`
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
id=${idArr[$i]}
val=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:100*$id/quantumrange]" info:`
convert image.jpg \
\( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 \) \
\( id_image.png -fuzz $fuzz% -fill white -opaque "gray($val%)" -fill black +opaque white -negate \) \
-compose over -composite image_$i.png
done
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

For Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick.